# R recode a character column in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column in a data table that contains names of variables. The column name is `nutrient`. For display purposes I want to replace a variable name in this column like "vit_c_mg" to "Vitamin C". I have a list of the old and new variables.  I could do something like

```
for (i in 1:length(list1){
    DT[nutrient %in% list1[i], nutrient := list2[i]]
}
```

but there must be a better data.table way of doing this.

Comment: Post a small example. You should make clear whether the translation table covers all values in `DT$nutrient`.

Answer (score 4):

I happen to have small dta.table named dt

```
dt
    x y z          d1 d2
 1: 1 1 b 0.948027912  1
 2: 2 2 a 0.926351588  1
 3: 4 1 a 0.555704929  1
 4: 4 1 a 0.987548561  1
 5: 2 1 a 0.093421508  1
```

It's pretty easy to use an existing column value to index a translation table:

```
 dt[ , z := c(a="v",b="w")[z] ]

> dt
    x y z          d1 d2
 1: 1 1 w 0.948027912  1
 2: 2 2 v 0.926351588  1
 3: 4 1 v 0.555704929  1
 4: 4 1 v 0.987548561  1
 5: 2 1 v 0.093421508  1
```

The values of `nutrient` should match up with the names in the translation vector. There needs to be a name in the vector for every current value in the column or you will get NA's. (Might be safer to create a new column before discarding the old values.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @42- is ok but I choose to go a different route. `list1` is the unique set of common names in `dt`. `list2` is the converted names. `dt.temp` is essentially a lookup table.

```
dt.temp <- data.table(list1 = list1, list2 = list2]
dt <- merge(dt, dt.table, by.x = "nutrient", by.y = "list1")
dt[, nutrient:= NULL]
setnames(DT, old = "list2", new = "nutrient]
```